# All solutions to this equation?

Tags: trigonometry

$\cos(2x)-\sqrt{3}\cos(x)+10\cos(x)+1-5\sqrt{3}=0$

Is this the same as $-(\sqrt{3}-2\cos(x))(\cos(x)+5)=0$

And if so, what are the solutions? I can't figure this out...

Comment: Whenever you get a product of terms equal to zero, at least one of them must be zero. So try each term and you'll find all possible answers.

Answer (score 4):

The equation $\cos x+5=0$ has no solution (why ?). Hence you have to solve

$\sqrt{3}-2\cos(x)=0$

Comment: Not in the reals, at least.